# How to copy a directory structure without copying files?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I have a folder with a lot of subfolders and files in them. Is there a way to copy the folder and subfolders directory structure **without** copying the files they contain, using cmd or powershell?

Answer (score 53):

This will copy the complete sub-directory structure contained in the source directory to the destination directory without including any files.

```
xcopy <source> [<destination>] /t /e
```

| Option | Description |
| --- | --- |
| **`/t`** | Copies the subdirectory structure (that is, the tree) only, not files. To copy empty directories, you must include the `/e` command-line option. |
| **`/e`** | Copies all subdirectories, even if they are empty. Use `/e` with the `/s` and `/t` command-line options. |

**Microsoft Documentation:**   [xcopy command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy)

Comment: correct, `/e` should be used, too.

Comment: XCOPY Build in Powershell by default and works perfectly.

Answer (score 30):

Yup. XCOPY

```
XCopy source {destination}  /t
```

example

```
xcopy C:\Folders D:\Folders /t
```

more about xcopy can be found here http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html

Comment: You should add `/e` to copy also empty folders

Answer (score 28):

Although XCOPY still works, Windows Vista and later include ROBOCOPY which has more features.  General syntax for copying a folder tree (including empty folders) without the files is:

`robocopy "A:\Source folder" "B:\Destination folder" /e /xf *`

Comment: /COPYALL should also take care of security info (ACLs)

Answer (score 4):

PowerShell method that doesn't require copying each file and then deleting them:

```
Copy-Item -LiteralPath '.\source' -Destination 'C:\path\to\copy' -Recurse -Filter {PSIsContainer -eq $true}
```

Or more succinctly:

```
copy .\source C:\path\to\copy -r -fi PSIsContainer
```

The only interesting trick here is the filtering on the `PSIsContainer` property, which is true for directories but not files.

Comment: This is super quick as well!

Answer (score 0):

Look at 47folders app, free, handy Windows  tool, does exactly what you need through nice GUI.
[image]

WARNING: Former link (http://47foldersapp.com/) now (Nov 2017) leads to advertisement for clothing. 
The last good Internet Archive copy is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161223020908/http://47foldersapp.com/). 
Software may still be available from freeware download sites
such as [this one](http://www.brothersoft.com/47-folders-485479.html).

Answer (score 0):

I just used the freeware Miroirs, which very simply copied just  folders, not the contents (though that is an option).

http://www.scanialabs.com/Products/Miroirs/Miroirs.aspx

Answer (score -1):

There's probably a better solution, but I'd see these:

- Copy everything, then empty the folders with a script.
- Make a script that will copy everything if it has no extension. Unless you have files without an extension in the folders, which you shouldn't, it should work, because, well. Folders don't have extensions. Something that would look like this in pseudocode:

open_directory($path);
while($file=get_directory_content) {
if(empty(get_file_extension($file))) {
copy_the_file($file,$destination);
}
}
close_directory;

Comment: Unfortunatelly, we do have files without extensions. From .placeholders for code repos, to some specific data files.

Comment: Oh. Well. Maybe there's an if(it's a folder) thing, then. But uhm. The xcopy thing above seems like it's the right thing for you then. Unless it's not, in which case you can run a script to 1. copy all folders and 2. empty all folders. Or something. But this is... Long. xD

Answer (score -1):

as far as I know there are third party software which may provide this functionality if you want to do with command prompt then copy command is out there. type 
    **help copy** in cmd which provides details on how you copy files through cmd. 
after copying go to the folder through cmd and run command

```
del*.*
```

which deletes files because folders not having . character

Comment: Deletes files all right, but who says folder names cannot contain a dot/period as well?

Answer (score -1):

Use PowerShell to do that using. Make Copy of Folder and then
`Remove-Item -Path "C:\test\*.*" -recurse`